# Why do I get these warnings when I run some npm react commands?

Tags: reactjs, npm

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be because the package you're trying to install was optimized for previous npm versions. But in most cases it should be fine.
you can use`--force` to avoid errors